# Angular JS (1.2.26) promises in a forEach loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, onload, angular-promise

I have an angular.forEach loop that iterates over image config objects in order to create javascript Image() objects based on a URL in the config.

I *don't* want the resulting images to be returned until all of them have properly loaded. How can I achieve this trough the use of Angular promises?

Consider the following (simplified) code snippet:

```
function getImages(imageConfigurations) {
    var images = [];

    angular.forEach(imageConfigurations, function (config) {
        var imageObject = loadImageFromUrl(config.url);

        var imageData = {
            name: config.name,
            order: config.order,
            image: imageObject
        };

        images.push(imageData);

    });

    //Do not return this untill all of the image objects from forEach loop 
    //have fired their 'onload' event
    return images;

}

function loadImageFromUrl(url) {
    var imageObj = new Image();

    imageObj.onload = function () {
        //Resolve promise?
    };

    imageObj.src = url;
}
```

Comment: You probably want [`$q.all()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all). Make your `loadImageFromUrl` call return a promise from [`$q.defer()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-deferred-api) and resolve it on the `onload`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following requires you inject the [`$q`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) service...

First thing you can do is wrap the image loading in a promise, eg

```
function loadImageFromUrl(url) {
    return $q(function(resolve) { // ignoring error conditions for now
        var imageObj = new Image();

        imageObj.onload = function () {
            resolve(imageObj);
        };

        imageObj.src = url;
    });        
}
```

Then, you can use [`$q.all`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all) to wait for all the promises to resolve

```
function getImages(imageConfigurations) {
    // map imageConfigurations to an array of promises
    var promises = imageConfigurations.map(function(config) {
        return loadImageFromUrl(config.url).then(function(imageObj) {
            // chain the loadImageFromUrl promise to create the
            // imageData object and return it to resolve the promise
            return {
                name: config.name,
                order: config.order,
                image: imageObj
            };
        });
    });

    return $q.all(promises);
}
```

When that promise resolves, you will have an array of your `imageData` objects

```
getImages(configs).then(function(imageDataArray) {
    // tada!
});
```

---

Here's the version of `loadImageFromUrl` you'll need for Angular 1.2.x. See https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.26/docs/api/ng/service/$q

```
function loadImageFromUrl(url) {
    var deferred = $q.defer(),
        imageObj = new Image();

    imageObj.onload = function () {
        deferred.resolve(imageObj);
    };
    imageObj.src = url;

    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Didn't even know you could create a promise by doing $q(...) thanks!

Comment: @MathewBerg it's a recent addition. I find it looks nicer than creating a deferred object though functionally I think they're the same

Comment: @Phil: We're limited to an older version of Angular for this project (1.2.6 I believe). Will $q(...) still work?

Comment: @LucMorrissette you really should have mentioned that earlier. No, you'll need to use a deferred object. I've updated my answer

Answer (score -1):

notice that getImages is now async -

```
  function getImages(imageConfigurations) {
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     var images = [];
     var imagePromises = imageConfigurations.map(function (config) {
         var imagePromise = loadImageFromUrl(config.url);
         return imagePromise;
     });

     return $q.all(imagePromises).then(function(images){
          return images.map(function(imageObject){
             // create image object 
           })
        });
 }
```

load images from url is now async also -

```
   function loadImageFromUrl(url) {
         var defer = $q.defer();
         var imageObj = new Image();

         imageObj.onload = function () {
            defer.resolve("image has been loaded - yay");
         };

         imageObj.src = url;

         return defer.promise;
     }
```

for the $q documentation go here - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

good luck

Comment: One big problem I see here is that the `config` items required to create the image data object (`name` and `order`) won't be available when you need them. You could change it but then this answer would look even more like the one above

Comment: Another problem is `loadImageFromUrl` resolves with a string. `getImages` doesn't return an Array of resolved image promises, it returns an array of promises resolved to "yay".